# Delete any container using templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates

I have a lot of code where I am deleting vector containers that have pointers in them, that is, I have to delete all the pointers first and then clear the container. Every time I would iterate through and delete the pointers manually (I am aware of stl::algorithms for_each). To circumvent all that code, I created a template for deleting all vector containers that have a pointer. So far so good.

Now I have several more container types including maps, concurrent containers etc. all with the same functionality in the end as far as deletion goes. The `DeleteContainer(std::vector<T*>& VecIn)` function that I have can only work on vectors as mentioned above. Is there any way to make it generic enough to work on all containers?

> **EDIT:** Thanks for all the answers, I wish I could select more than one. To anybody who stumbles onto this question, read all the answers and not just the selected one as they all provide great info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have a valid answer, but just to provide an alternative, I believe you should consider using [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) and let it handle memory management :

> This library therefore provides
>   standard-like containers that are for
>   storing heap-allocated or cloned
>   objects (or in case of a map, the
>   mapped object must be a heap-allocated
>   or cloned object). **For each of the
>   standard containers there is a pointer
>   container equivalent that takes
>   ownership of the objects in an
>   exception safe manner.**

Answer (score 4):

You could use boost pointer containers.
They hold maintain and delete pointers correctly.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html

```
{
    boost::ptr_vector<int>   data;

    data.push_back(new int(2));
    data.push_back(new int(2));
    data.push_back(new int(2));
}
// container deleted and all pointers correctly destroyed.
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll second many people and avise using `shared_ptr` or boost pointer containers. However, you can write

```
template <typename Iter>  
void delete_pointers(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) delete *begin;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<Foo*> v;

// Initialize Foo objects

delete_pointers(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

I use `rbegin` and `rend` instead of `begin` and `end` because sometimes, people want objects to be deleted in the reverse order they were created.

You can also do

```
void destroyFoo(Foo* x) { delete x; }

std::for_each(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), &destroyFoo);
```

or use C++0x lambdas.

Comment: Only comment I would add is that you'd have to handle associative containers differently, as you can't call delete on the `pair`.

Comment: @Nim: very good point. You cannot iterate on keys or values easily with C++ maps, you have to write a "second_iterator" adapter.

Comment: Will ::operator delete just deallocate memory or will it also call the destructor? I have my doubts here...

Comment: @tomek: to be honest, I have doubts too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 'operator delete' is basically C++'s 'free', so no the dtors won't be called.  5.3.5/6 refers to the 'delete-expression' invoking the destructor, and then 5.3.5/7 states that "The delete-expression will call a deallocation-function".  And "operator delete" is one of the deallocation-functions.  But as with most answers here, they are all forgetting about the delete[] cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `boost::shared_ptr<T>` insted of `T*` and there will not be reason of `DeleteContainer`. But If you don't want to do this, you can make something like this

```
template<class T>
void DeleteContainer(typename T::iterator begin, typename T::iterator end)
{
 for(;begin!=end;++begin)
  delete *begin;
}
```

then you can just call it for any stl container you want in this way:

```
std::some_container<int*> s;
DeleteContainer<std::some_container<int*> > (s.begin(), s.end());
```

Comment: This is not very C++ ish. The container is not exception safe as you are calling the deleter manually. You need to wrap the container in ab object so that RAII actually calls the function automatically when the container goes out of scope.

Comment: Same comment as the other answer, you have to handle associative containers differently.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Tomek, we can have a similar solution to handle the deletion. A struct would have been better than a free function.

```
struct Delete
{
   public:
      template<typename T>
      void operator()(const T* ptr) const
      {
          delete ptr;
      }
      void operator()(const char* ptr) const
      {
          delete[] ptr;

     }
};
```

for_each(some_container.begin(), some_container.end(), Delete());

Comment: Why is this better than a free function?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to give up on deleting things entirely and commit to using a garbage collector :) You can try the Boehm-Reiser-Detlefs collector, it is standard on Linux (libgc) and it is used in many complex programs now (such as gcc). It's also a good idea to give up on RAII: it was a nice idea at the time but it doesn't work so well in practice. Many resources are independently created and destroyed out of order with their representation.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this would be:

```
template<class T>
void Destroy(T *p)
{
  delete p;
}

template<template<typename, typename> class C, typename T1, typename T2>
void Destroy(C<T1 *, T2> &c)
{                                                        
  std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), Destroy<T1>);
}
```

Tested on g++ 4.4.4 with vector, deque and list. You may need additional overloads of void Destroy(C<T1 *, T2> &c) for other containers and/or other STL implementations.

Comment: This does not handle the case of std::some_container<char*>. Since, some_container<char*> is more often used than some_container<primitive_type*>, it's better to handle char* case.