# Deallocating vector of pointers, but memory still in use

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, vector

I have no idea what's wrong with the following code! I am deleting all pointers, but when I use the "top" command to watch the memory, I can see that still lots of memory is allocated to the program. Am I missing something here to free the memory?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int*> container;
    vector<int*>::iterator itr;
    unsigned long long i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        int* temp = new int();
        *temp = 1;
        container.push_back(temp);
    }

    for(itr = container.begin(); itr != container.end(); itr++)
    {
        delete *itr;
        *itr = NULL;
    }

    container.clear();
    cout<<"\nafter clear\n";

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1000000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Top is NOT the program you should use to determine if you have memory leaks

Comment: Your memory is freed. But memory is never returned to the OS (until the processes terminates). So `top` will never see the memory go down.

Comment: If you have a real program which you suspect leaks (not this toy). Then you should run valgrind against it (that should uncover most of your problems). Alternatively you should write C++ and not C code and use RAII

Comment: @Martin: how is it that if I delete the pointer right after I allocate memory to it (within the for loop), I don't see memory go up

Comment: Top is not designed for what you are trying to use it for. Top will give you an estimate of the memory allocated by the OS to the processes. It will **not** indicate how much of that memory is currently being used. The processes internally will manage all the new/delete calls and track the usage of memory that has been allocated to it (it will ask for more whenever it needs more memory but rarely does it return it to the OS). So new *may* cause the memory usage to go up, but delete will not (probably) make it go down. Use the appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no leak in this code (Assuming there are no exceptions being thrown after allcoation and before deallocation). The reason why that you are not seeing memory coming down is that the CRT may not release the memory you `delete` immediately back to the process. It might keep it for future use. However, it is guaranteed that the memory will be released once the process terminates.

Comment: Naveen, is there any way we can force the CRT to release the memory immediately? In the real-world application, we are dealing with the same problem. The application runs out of memory after a while which makes it bogged down due to lack of enough memory available on the server! We have also analyzed the application using Valgrind and have found no memory leak.

Comment: This is an OS thing. The OS should reclaim the memory when it needs it somewhere else.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.18-5-686 (Debian 2.6.18.dfsg.1-13) (gcc version 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21))

Comment: From the symptoms you are describing it seems you are running out of RAM, but I don't know how to solve it though.

Comment: @Maysam: There may be memory leaks that are not that easy to track: A "Classic" memory leak is a peace of allocated memory that is never freed. A search for those memory leaks just looks which memory is not freed after the program terminates normally. BUT there are leaks that are cleaned up on termination but not in between! (i.e.: Pointers are added to a list. The list is cleaned (memory freed) on termination but while the program runs it just allocates and adds. So a normal leak search will find nothing but your program eats up all memory while running!

Answer (score 0):

As Naveen said, there is no leak in the code. But, the way you are writing loop is not recommended. You could have easily used for_each() to delete the memory. [refer to this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479381/delete-any-container-using-templates/4481170#4481170)

Comment: Why are those loops not recommended? Just because they may be slightly faster since the compiler could do some more optimizations? But they are much more easy to code and read than a for_each that needs a functor class declared...

Comment: Look at the post increment of iterator in the loop. I was refering to that. Well I could have been more specific though. Anyways, he could have avoided that issue had he used for_each.