# Burst memory usage in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am trying to get a handle on proper memory usage and garbage collection in Java. I'm not a novice programmer by any means, but it always seems to me that once Java touches some memory, it will never be released for other applications to use. In that case, you have to make sure your **peak memory** is never too high, or your application will continually use whatever the peak memory usage was.

I wrote a small sample program trying to demonstrate this. It basically has 4 buttons...

1. Fill class scope variable `BigList = new ArrayList<string>()` with about 25,000,000 long string items.
2. Call `BigList.clear()`
3. Reallocate the list - `BigList = new ArrayList<string>()` again (to shrink the list size)
4. A call to `System.gc()` - Yes, I know this doesn't mean that GC will really run, but it's what we have.

So next I did some testing on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS while using the default task monitors to check on the processes reported memory usage. Here is what I found...

- **Windows** - Pumping the list, calling clear, and then calling GC several times will not reduce memory usage at all. However, reallocating the list using `new` and then calling GC several times will reduce the memory usage back to starting levels. IMO, this is acceptable.
- **Linux** (I used Mint 11 distro with Sun JVM) - Same results as Windows.
- **Mac OS** - I followed the sames steps as above, but even when reinitializing the list calls to GC seemingly have no effect. The program will sit using hundreds of MB of RAM even though I have nothing in memory.

**Can anyone explain this to me?** Some people have told me some stuff about "heap" memory, but I still don't fully understand it and I'm not sure it applies here. From what I have heard about it, I shouldn't be seeing the behavior I am on Windows and Linux anyways.

Is this just a difference in the way Mac OS's Activity Monitor measures memory usage or is there something else going on? I would prefer to not have my program idling with tons of RAM usage. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: It is unclear waht you mean by "memory" and "released". RAM, virtual memory?

Comment: Let's define it as "The amount of physical memory immediately available to the operating system for use in other applications". Does that work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Sun/Oracle JVM does not return unneeded memory to the system. If you give it a large, maximum heap size, and you actually use that heap space at some point, the JVM won't give it back to the OS for other uses. Other JVMs will do that (JRockit used to, but I don't think it does any more).

So, for Oracles JVM you need to tune your app and your system for peak usage, that's just how it works. If the memory that you're using can be managed with byte arrays (such as working with images or something), then you can use mapped byte buffers instead of Java byte arrays. Mapped byte buffers are taken straight from the system, and are not part of the heap. When you free up these objects (AND they are GC'd, I believe, but not sure), the memory will be returned to the system. You'll likely have to play with that one assuming it's even applicable at all.

Comment: Good answer, lots of stuff i didn't know.

Comment: Do you know why in the Windows/Linux Task Manager then it would appear as if it is releasing memory? I'm trying to figure out if it is still really retaining the memory and the Task Manager just makes it look as if it's not. Mac OS seems to act the way you say it should.

Comment: @jocull - It's very easy to confuse what the various metrics are that task manager is measuring (Working set vs VM size is usually confused).  IME, you should do your measurements with a heap analyzer to track metrics and merely use the OS task manager as a gut check.

Comment: @Will I was really surprised to discover that recent Oracle JVM (Java 6) running an Swing application on Windows forces collection and compaction, so returns memory to the OS when the application window is minimized. IBM JVM also returns memory to the operating system.

Comment: @YvesMartin If you're talking about the working set, that's been reduced on application minimize since at least java 1.4.  Note though that the working set has no correlation to the heap size.

Comment: I am not a Windows specialist - I have only seen the "memory" value decreased in process explorer and thought it was a Java heap size compaction.

Answer (score 6):

> ... but it always seems to me that once Java touches some memory, it's gone forever. You will never get it back.

It depends on what you mean by "gone forever".

I've also heard it said that some JVMs *do* give memory back to the OS when they are ready and able to.  Unfortunately, given the way that the low-level memory APIs typically work, the JVM has to give back entire segments, and it tends to be complicated to "evacuate" a segment so that it can be given back.

But I wouldn't rely on that ... because there are various things that could prevent the memory being given back.  The chances are that the JVM *won't* give the memory back to the OS.  But it is not "gone forever" in the sense that the JVM will continue to make use of it.  Even if the JVM never approaches the peak usage again, all of that memory will help to make the garbage collector run more efficiently.

> In that case, you have to make sure your peak memory is never too high, or your application will continually eat up hundreds of MB of RAM.

That is not true.  Assuming that you are adopting the strategy of starting with a small heap and letting it grow, the JVM won't ask for significantly more memory than the peak memory.  The JVM won't continually eat up more memory ... unless your application has a memory leak and (as a result) its peak memory requirement has no bound.

(The OP's comments below indicate that this is not what he was trying to say.  Even so, it is what he did say.)

---

On the topic of garbage collection efficiency, we can model the cost of a run of an efficient garbage collector as:

```
cost ~= (amount_of_live_data * W1) + (amount_of_garbage * W2)
```

where W1 and W2 are (we assume) constants that depend on the collector.  (Actually, this is an over-simplification.  The first part is not a linear function of the number of live objects.  However, I claim that it doesn't matter for the following.)

The *efficiency* of the collector can then be stated as:

```
efficiency = cost / amount_of_garbage_collected
```

which (if we assume that the GC collects all data) expands to

```
efficiency ~= (amount_of_live_data * W1) / amount_of_garbage + W2.
```

When the GC runs,

```
heap_size ~= amount_of_live_data + amount_of_garbage
```

so

```
efficiency ~= W1 * (amount_of_live_data / (heap_size - amount_of_live_data) )
              + W2.
```

In other words:

- as you increase the heap size, the efficiency tends to a constant (W2), but
- you need a large ratio of heap_size to amount_of_live_data for this to happen.

The other point is that for an efficient copying collector, W2 covers just the cost of zeroing the space occupied by the garbage objects in 'from space'.  The rest (tracing, copying of live objects to 'to space", and zeroing the 'from space' that they occupied) is part of the first term of the initial equation; i.e. covered by W1.  What this means is that W2 is likely to be considerably smaller than W1 ... and that the first term of the final equation is significant for longer.

Now obviously this is a theoretical analysis, and the cost model is a simplification of how real garbage collectors really work.  (And it doesn't take account of the "real" work that the application is doing, or the system-level effects of tying down too much memory.)  However, the maths tells me that *from the standpoint of GC efficiency*, a big heap really does help *a lot*.

Comment: The garbage collector shouldn't need that much extra memory to run efficiently.  Regarding the second quote, you're not contradicting the poster in any way.  He's basically asking why the memory usage never declines from the peak, even when the actual memory needs decline.

Comment: @Stephen, you bring up some good points. A few minor additions - JVM to OS memory interactions are optimized for performance reasons and so memory may not be *immediately* released back to the OS even if it is unused in the heap - it will be eventually if it remains unused for a *long time*, the definition of long time being dependent on the environment. The max heap is bounded (Xmx) so apps don't continually eat up more and more RAM, they would hit a ceiling and complain of OOM if the app needs more. I won't worry about idle memory because app may need it which will be reclaimed if it doesnt.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - Any known garbage collector will work more efficiently as the proportion of garbage to non-garbage increases.  This is more pronounced with copying collectors, but it applies to mark-sweep and mark-sweep-compact collectors as well.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - Re your 2nd point.  My reading of the section I quoted is that he asserts that the memory keeps growing.  Maybe that's not what he meant ... but it is what he literally wrote.  (I'm a native English speaker, by the way.)

Comment: I meant "gone forever" in terms of usage for other applications. The JVM doesn't seem to release, so other applications may never use. For the 2nd quote I meant that it will continually use whatever the peak memory was. If at some point you used 200MB of RAM, it seems that you might always use 200MB regardless of current needs. Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: @Stephen, I think "eat up" just meant "occupy" (given he later wrote "The program will sit using hundreds of MB of RAM"), but I agree it could have been phrased better.  I agree effective GC requires *some* extra memory, but there's a point where there's minimal extra benefit.

Answer (score 3):

**Some JVMs do not or are not able to release previously acquired memory back to the host OS if it isn't needed atm.** This is because it's a costly and complex task. The garbage collector only applies to the heap memory *within the Java virtual machine.* Therefore it does not give back (`free()` in `C` terms) memory to the OS. E.g. if a big object isn't used any more, the memory will be marked as free within the heap of the JVM by the GC and not released to OS.

However, the situation is changing, for example [ZGC will return memory to the operating system](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/zgc/Main#Main-ReturningUnusedMemorytotheOperatingSystem).

Answer (score 2):

Once the program terminates, is the memory usage getting down in taskmanager in windows ? I think the memory is getting released but not shown as released by the default task monitors in the OS you are monitoring. Go through this question on C++ [Problem with deallocating vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537556/problem-with-deallocating-vector-of-pointers/4537629#4537629.)

Comment: I think it is clear that "The program will sit using hundreds of MB of RAM even though I have nothing in memory." that he is letting the program continue to run, but with low memory needs (since the list is now empty).  The memory will be reclaimed when the JVM exits, but that's not the question.

Comment: Yes, the memory is reclaimed when the JVM terminates. It doesn't seem to be reclaimed while the JVM is alive on Mac OS.

Comment: On Ubuntu, yes, the memory is reclaimed **only** when the java process exits. That's why LiClipse/PyDev with one small project can take 7,5Gb of memory + 4Gb of swap and continue growing by bursts until a OOM happens. Most of the memory is cached memory and yet cannot be released by the system while the process is alive.

Answer (score 2):

A common misconception is that Java uses up memory as it runs and there for it should be able to return memory to the OS.  Actually the Oracle/Sun JVM reserves the virtual memory as a continuous block of memory as soon as it starts. If the isn't enough continuous virtual memory available it fails on start up even if the program isn't going to use that much.

What then happens is the OS is smart enough not to allocate physical memory to the program until it is used.  It cannot easily reclaim the memory  but it can be swapped to disk if it needs to and it hasn't been used for a while.  Java doesn't handle having parts of the heap swapped to disk very well so this should be avoided.

Comment: The big problem I have with this is explaining it to users. "Oh, I swear I coded this right. Don't worry about it using 500MB of RAM all the time, it will be swapped out to disk when it's not actually doing anything." I don't think they buy that, and it feels like a big flaw in the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Java allocate memory only to objects. There is no explicit allocation of memory. In-fact Java even treats array types as objects. Each time an object created it comes in heap.

The Java runtime employs a garbage collector that reclaims the memory occupied by an object once it determines that object is no longer accessible. This is automatic process.

Calling `System.gc()` may not collect garbage at the time you call it; thats why your memory is not reduced. In general, it is better to let the system decide when it needs to collect the heap, and whether or not to do a full collection.

`System.gc()` doesn't even force a garbage collection; it's simply a **hint to the JVM** that "now may be a good time to clean up a bit"

Java memory explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/858650/420613) [link2](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which I think can be summarized as, "Why isn't the memory reclaimed in this case?"

Comment: Its a business. Calling System.gc() may slow your application. These links will be useful http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html. http://www.sap-img.com/java/garbage-collection-cannot-be-forced.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are some great documents produced by Sun/Oracle describing Java's Garbage Collection. A quick search on "Java Garbage Collection Tuning" yeilds results such as;
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html
and 
http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/

The introduction of the Oracle doc states;

> The Java TM 2 Platform Standard Edition (J2SE TM platform) is used for
>   a wide variety of applications from small applets on desktops to web
>   services on large servers. In the J2SE platform version 1.4.2 there
>   were four garbage collectors from which to choose but without an
>   explicit choice by the user the serial garbage collector was always
>   chosen. In version 5.0 the choice of the collector is based on the
>   class of the machine on which the application is started.
>
> This “smarter choice” of the garbage collector is generally better but
>   is not always the best. For the user who wants to make their own
>   choice of garbage collectors, this document will provide information
>   on which to base that choice. This will first include the general
>   features of the garbage collections and tuning options to take the
>   best advantage of those features. The examples are given in the
>   context of the serial, stop-the-world collector. Then specific
>   features of the other collectors will be discussed along with factors
>   that should considered when choosing one of the other collectors.

They describe the various types of collectors available and the situations in which they should be used. I remember using this alongside [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to montior how the application performed when started with various different options.

These docs will give you a bit more insight into how collection occurs depending on the parameters you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on Windows and have found a solution, so I'm posting it as an answer in case it can help others.

A lot of answers on here suggest that Java's behavior is 1. good and/or 2. an unavoidable consequence of garbage collecting.  These are both false.

**The Problem:**

If you are like me and you want to write Java to write small applications for a workstation or even run multiple smaller processes on a server, then Oracle's JVM memory allocation behavior makes it almost completely useless.  Even when running with -client, every JVM process hoards memory once allocated and never gives it back.  This behavior cannot be disabled.  As the OP notices: each jvm process holds on to its unused memory indefinitely even if it will never use it again and even while other jvm processes are starving.  This inexplicable behavior makes Oracle's a useless implementation for all but monolithic, single-application scenarios.

Also: this is NOT a consequence of garbage collection.  Witness .Net applications which run on Windows, use garbage collection, and do not suffer from this problem at all.

**The Solution:**

The solution I found to this was to use the [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) JVM which you use as a drop-in replacement for java.exe on windows.  It compiles Java bytecode to .Net IL code and runs as a .Net process.  It also contains utilities to convert .jar files into .Net .dll and .exe assemblies.  The performance is often better than Oracle's JVM and after a GC, memory is instantly returned to the OS.  (Note: this also works in Linux with Mono)

To be clear, I still rely on Oracle's JVM for all but my small applications and also to debug my small applications, but once stable, I use ikvm to run them as if they were native windows applications and this works so well, I've been amazed.  It has numerous beneficial side effects.  Once compiled, DLLs shared between processes are loaded only once, and applications show up in the task manager as .exe instead of all showing as javaw.exe.

Unfortunately, not everyone can use ikvm to solve this problem, but I hope this helps those in my situation.

Comment: That's really cool. It makes distribution more difficult, and I'm not sure how well it would work with Mac. Java wasn't so bad about the memory on Windows, but it was **really** bad on Mac. May just be differences in how each OS reports memory usage.