# SOLR memory consumption after indexing with DIH

Tags: solr, jetty, dih

I'm using solr 3.6. I'm indexing using DIH aprox 2.6GB of data hourly (right now, I use full import, but I knows about delta imports as well). I'm using 24GB of RAM just for JVM. The solr   instance is a multicore implementation (right now with 8 cores, but that will grow), but only one core have big index (aprox 2.6GB). What I observ is the RAM usage is increasing after every full index and never come back till I don't restart the servlet container (jetty). 
Here is an image of the data from New Relic:
[image: jetty snapshot from New Relic]

Is it an issue or a bug from solr? I guess the problem is whit garbage collection.
Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Is it Linux or is it Windows with MS SQL Server?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 12.04 server edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is totally fine, no bug. In java, if you allocate X amount of ram to the heap, the jvm will happily use it as it needs, and it might take a while to release it, or even not release it until it needs the memory for new objects.

See more details [in other questions about java memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265240/burst-memory-usage-in-java)